# Table specifically built for a dashboard has several filters.... best way to index?

Tags: postgresql

I have created a materialized view for the purposes of feeding into a dashboard.

My goal is to make this table selectable in the fastest way possible and I'm not sure how to approach it. I was hoping that if I describe the table and how it will be used, someone could offer some direction.

The context is a website with funnel steps.Each row is an instance of a user triggering a funnel step such as add to cart, checkout, payment details and then finally transaction.

Since the table is for the purposes of analytics, it will be refreshed automatically with cron once a day only, in the morning, so I'm not worried about real time update speed, only select speed with various where clauses.

Suppose I have the fields described below:

(N = ~13M and expected to be ~20 by January, growing several million per month)
Table is unique with the combination of session id, user id and funnel step.

```
 - Session Id (Id, so some duplication but generally very very granular - Varchar)
 - User Id (Id, so some duplication but generally very very granular - Varchar)
 - Date (Date)
 - Funnel Step (10 distinct value - Varchar)
 - Device Category (3 distinct values - Varchar)
 - Country (~ 100 distinct values - varchar)
 - City (~1000+ distinct values - varchar)
 - Source (several thousand distinct values, nevertheless, stakeholder would like a filter - varchar)
```

Would I index each field individually? Or, should I index all fields in a oner? [Per the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/sql-createindex.html), I think I can index up to 32 fields at once. But would that be advisable here given my primary goal of select query speed over everything else?

The table will feed into  dashboard that reads the table and dynamically translates filter inputs into where clauses. Each time the user adjusts a filter, the table will be read and grouped and aggregated based on the filter / where clause inputs.

Example query:

```
select 
  event_action,
  count(distinct user_id) as users
from website_data.ecom_funnel
where date >= $input_start_date
and date <= $input_end_date
and device_category in ($mobile, $desktop, $tablet)
and country in ($list of all countries minus any not selected)
and source in ($list of all sources minus any not selected)
group by 1 order by users desc
```

This will result in a funnel shaped table of data.

I cannot aggregate before hand because the primary metric of concern is users, not sessions. These must be de-duped from the underlying table. Classic example... Suppose a person visits a website once a day for a week. Then the sum of unique visitors for that week is 1, however if I summed visitors by day I would get 7. Similar with my table, some users take multiple sessions to complete the funnel. So, this is why I cannot pre aggregate the table, since I need to apply filters to the underlying data and then `count(distinct user id)`.

Here's explain on a subset of fields if it is useful:

```
QUERY PLAN
Sort  (cost=862194.66..862194.68 rows=9 width=24)
  Sort Key: (count(DISTINCT client_id)) DESC
  ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=847955.01..862194.51 rows=9 width=24)
        Group Key: event_action
        ->  Sort  (cost=847955.01..852701.48 rows=1898589 width=37)
              Sort Key: event_action
              ->  Seq Scan on ecom_funnel  (cost=0.00..589150.14 rows=1898589 width=37)
                    Filter: ((device_category = ANY ('{mobile,desktop}'::text[])) AND (source = 'google'::text))
```

My overarching, specific question is, given my use case, should I index each field individually or should I create one single index? Does it matter?

On top of that, any tips for optimising this materialized view to run a select query faster would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your filter conditions, you should check the cardinality of device_category field by posting

```
select device_category, count(*) from website_data.ecom_funnel group by device_category
```

and looking at the values to determine if an index should firstly include this column. Possible index here (without knowing the cardinality) would be multicolumn and include:

```
(device_category, date)
```

Saying that, there's no benefit from creating indexes on each separate column as your query wouldn't use them all, so it does matter. You would slow down other CRUD operations that aren't Read operation.

Creating an index on all columns won't probably speed it up too much for you as well, but that's based on the data lying under the hood (in the table) and how your filters compare to the overall query without them (cardinality of values in columns being filtered). This would most likely create a huge overhead of going through the index tree and then obtaining rowids to return the data you need.

Summing up, I would try to narrow the index down to the columns that matter most in your filtering which means they cut most of the data being retrieved. If your query is meant to return majority of rows from the table then there's a need to aggregate, unfortunately, as this wouldn't speed things up.

Hope it helps.

---

**Edit**: I've just read that you already posted count of distinct values among your table. I'm not sure what Funnel Step is bound to in your table, but assuming it's a column named event_action, it might be beneficial to instead create an index that would help in grouping as well by doing:

```
(date, event_action)
```

It seems like you have omitted the `GROUP BY` clause at all, which should be included and it should be grouping by event_action, since that's what your select part is doing.

If you narrow the date down to several days/months every time you perform a select query, it might be a huge benefit to create index with first `date` column.

Remember, that position of column in an index matters.

If you look for values from several months let's say, you should preaggregate and store precalculated values from each month in another table and then `UNION ALL` that data to the current query which would only select data from current (still being updated) time.

Comment: Hi Kamil, thank you for the information. Regarding cardinality, what's the rule of thumb here? The cardinality for device category is one of 3 values: about 50% 'mobile', about 40% 'desktop' and the remaining 10% 'tablet'.

Comment: That's a good start to think of putting this column into an index, but assuming that you aren't always picking all of those categories. If your select query always retrieves all of them, indexing this column is pointless. This means that if you got 50% of rows for mobile, the other 50% would get tossed away since it's not needed as per your query.

Comment: Also, re "Saying that, there's no benefit from creating indexes on each separate column as your query wouldn't use them all"

To clarify, when the query is run by the app, the where clause will indeed include each and every field (except the two ID fields). So device_category, city, country and source, will all be used. Does that change things?

Comment: Suppose a table with several million rows. Is the rule of thumb that if there's less granularity, like in the device category example, then this is a index candidate field? As opposed to say user_id, which is very granular and almost but not quite 1-1?

Comment: Even if you create 5 indexes your one select statement could use, optimizer will see which one of them it would be the most beneficial to use and will only use that one*. This is true almost all the time, except when you have partial indexes and they are all created on the same column, which is not your case.

Comment: Oh. So the optimiser will only ever use one index even if multiple are available? That's good to know.

Comment: @DougFir, regarding the granularity of column - yes, that's exactly right. The less distinct values vs all values there is for a column, the more beneficial it is for the index. You can create indexes and see what Postgres thinks of your query using `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`. The analyze part forces the query to actually execute and not only plan the query.

Comment: You can also play a bit with Postgres settings to see how it behaves if you for example force it to use an index scan instead of sequential scan (default behaviour - scanning whole table). This is only for experiment and to see how it behaves under the hood and should not be used as part of your stable production code, unless you really know better than the optimizer (really rare case). This is done using the `SET parameter ON/OFF` statement. Read about settings (that you see from EXPLAIN plan) here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-query.html

Comment: Thanks again, this is very helpful information. Since I'm still just learning Postgres, I will experiment with your suggestion. I will add an index for `(date, event_action)` and then another for `device_category` and see how that looks.

Comment: This might be useful to read: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-bitmap-scans.html